# How to listen for keyboard input and modify it to specific input?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a barcode scanner that acts as a keyboard input. I need it to only input "def" when I scan "abc,def" in any input field such as webpages, applications, etc.

This program will run on Windows 10 and 11.

The code includes three methods that I have tried.

I tried using the following code for global listening.

```
//install hook
public bool KeyboardStart()
{
    if (hKeyboardHook == 0)
    {
        hookproc = new HookProc(KeyboardHookProc);

        IntPtr moduleptr = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);

        hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, hookproc, moduleptr, 0);


        //WH_KEYBOARD_LL=13
        //hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, new HookProc(KeyboardHookProc), Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);
    }
    return (hKeyboardHook != 0);
}

//uninstall hook
public bool KeyboardStop()
{
    if (hKeyboardHook != 0)
    {
        return UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here are the methods attempted during listening with `KeyboardHookProc`.

```
private int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode == 0)
    {
        EventMsg msg = (EventMsg)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(EventMsg));
        if (wParam == 0x100)//WM_KEYDOWN=0x100
        {
            barCode.VirtKey = msg.message & 0xff;
            barCode.ScanCode = msg.paramL & 0xff;
            StringBuilder strKeyName = new StringBuilder(225);
            if (GetKeyNameText(barCode.ScanCode * 65536, strKeyName, 255) > 0)
            {
                barCode.KeyName = strKeyName.ToString().Trim(new char[] { ' ', '\0' });
            }
            else
            {
                barCode.KeyName = "";
            }
            byte[] kbArray = new byte[256];
            uint uKey = 0;
            GetKeyboardState(kbArray);


            if (ToAscii(barCode.VirtKey, barCode.ScanCode, kbArray, ref uKey, 0))
            {
                barCode.Ascll = uKey;
                barCode.Chr = Convert.ToChar(uKey);
            }

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(barCode.Time);

            if (ts.TotalMilliseconds > 50)
            {
                strBarCode = barCode.Chr.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if ((msg.message & 0xff) == 13 && strBarCode.Length > 3)
                {

                    barCode.BarCode = strBarCode;
                    barCode.IsValid = true;


                    //methods 1
                    //it can run on button click event and hook
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
                    int foregroundWindowProcessId;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, out foregroundWindowProcessId);
                    Process foregroundProcess = Process.GetProcessById(foregroundWindowProcessId);

                    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
                    int ct = 0;
                    IntPtr prevChild = IntPtr.Zero;
                    IntPtr currChild = IntPtr.Zero;

                    while (true && ct < 100)
                    {
                        currChild = FindWindowEx(foregroundProcess.MainWindowHandle, prevChild, null, null);
                        if (currChild == IntPtr.Zero) break;
                        result.Add(currChild);
                        prevChild = currChild;
                        ++ct;
                    }

                    Point caretPos = Cursor.Position;
                    IntPtr target = IntPtr.Zero;
                    target = WindowFromPoint(caretPos);

                    foreach (IntPtr hWnd in result)
                    {
                        if (hWnd == target)
                        {
                            Clipboard.SetText(BarcodeSplit(strBarCode) + "\r");
                            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_PASTE, 0, "");
                        }
                    }

                    private string BarcodeSplit(string str)
                    {
                        string[] BarcodeArray = str.Split(',');
                        if (LimitCode.Contains(BarcodeArray[2]))
                        {
                            return BarcodeArray[0];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return BarcodeArray[1];
                        }
                    }
                    //------------------------------------------------

                    //methods 2
                    //it can not run on hook
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
                    //set windows focus
                    SetForegroundWindow(foregroundWindow);

                    INPUT Input = new INPUT();
                    Input.type = 1; //keyboard_input
                    Input.ki.wVk = 0x42; //CAPS_Lock
                    Input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
                    SendInput(1, ref Input, Marshal.SizeOf(Input));

                    Input = new INPUT();
                    Input.type = 1;
                    Input.ki.wVk = 0x42;
                    Input.ki.dwFlags = 2;//key_up
                    SendInput(1, ref Input, Marshal.SizeOf(Input));

                    //------------------------------------------------

                    //methods 3
                    //it can not run on hook
                    //------------------------------------------------
                    IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
                    //set windows focus
                    SetForegroundWindow(foregroundWindow);
                    SendKeys.Send(barCode.BarCode);
                    //------------------------------------------------
                }
                strBarCode += barCode.Chr.ToString();
            }
            barCode.Time = DateTime.Now;
            if (BarCodeEvent != null) BarCodeEvent(barCode);
            barCode.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
    //stop keyboard key in
    return 1;
}

public struct BarCodes
{
    public int VirtKey;
    public int ScanCode;
    public string KeyName;
    public uint Ascll;
    public char Chr;
    public string BarCode;
    public bool IsValid;
    public DateTime Time;
}

private struct EventMsg
{
    public int message;
    public int paramL;
    public int paramH;
    public int Time;
    public int hwnd;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct INPUT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal int type;//0:mouse event;1:keyboard event;2:hardware event
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    internal ushort wVk;
    internal ushort wScan;
    internal uint dwFlags;
    internal uint time;
    internal IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, string windowTitle);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, string lParam);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern uint SendInput(uint nInput, ref INPUT pInput, int cbSize);
```

How can I modify it to achieve my desired goal?

If there is any missing description, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.